# Why is it get printed two times when I run webapp?It's template which is created by default I haven't changed anything

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, opera

I have index jsp file where i print to console some string, but it get printed two times

index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= "Hello World!" %>
</h1>
<br/>
<%System.out.println("iihii");%>
<a href="hello-servlet">Hello Servlet</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this on console

[image]

Why does it happen?

> Edit

I get this logs when I start web application

2021-05-30 22:48 INFO   LoggerFilter   doFilter   - - - - - Request Uri : /FinalProjectPM_war_exploded/Remote Addr : 127.0.0.1Protocol : HTTP/1.1
2021-05-30 22:48 INFO   indexJsp   _jspx_meth_log_005flog_005f0   - - - - - Index jsp has been visited

2021-05-30 22:48 INFO   LoggerFilter   doFilter   - - - - - Request Uri : /FinalProjectPM_war_exploded/Remote Addr : 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1Protocol : HTTP/1.1
2021-05-30 22:48 INFO   indexJsp   _jspx_meth_log_005flog_005f0   - - - - - Index jsp has been visited

Comment: Can you please add "hello-servlet" code?

Comment: Probably because `message` is initially `null` and then reassigned a value. Initialize `message` when you create it and don't reassign it in `init()`. I think the double will disappear.

Comment: @RandyCasburn,I edited post,hello servlet doesn't relate to my question, it stayed from my  previous question

Comment: This doesn't happen, unless your browser performs the request twice. Check your access log to see how many requests there were.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz - It can happen if the state of the controller changes while the JSP is being interpolated.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I edited post

Comment: You have two requests: one from the IPv4 localhost address and one from the IPv6 localhost address: which browser are you using?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I use Opera

Comment: Try with another browser or better `curl`: Opera might send requests to all IP addresses of a given domain. Something like [this bug](https://forums.opera.com/topic/36701/stop-opera-from-sending-urls-while-typing).